# VS CODE terminal cannot use proxy

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, proxy

I'm trying to run a project in VS CODE terminal but due to my proxy I'm not able to.

In File -> Preferences -> Settings -> User -> Application -> Proxy, I setup the proxy address as http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080. In settings.json, I put as followings:

```
{
    "http.proxy": "http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080",
    "https.proxy": "http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

Now I am able to search for extensions, but terminal is not working. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Writing here the solution that worked for me, might prove helpful to someone.
Also check the official documentation about [proxy-server-support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_proxy-server-support).

So what I did was run the following command in the terminal to open a new VSCode window:

```
code --proxy-server="http=<Your Ip Address>:<Your Port>"
```

OR in another format replacing the "X"s appropriately.

```
code --proxy-server="http=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"
```

You might also want to define the proxy URI for HTTPS, so your terminal command would look as below (It was not necessary in my case though).

```
code --proxy-server="http=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX;https=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"
```